# Replace single quotes around integer values in a text file using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch file programming. Need to write a batch file which can remove single quotes around integer values.

Actually, I was writing a batch file to prepare a SQL insert command from text file. Have almost completed but stuck at removing single quotes enclosing an integer.

Suppose, I have a text file, its content is like this.

```sh
'abc','def','123','1abc'

'xy','mncef','456','cd'
```

I would want a batch file to remove that upper quotes around integer and the output should be like this.

```sh
'abc','def',123,'1abc'

'xy','mncef',456,'cd'
```

I have tried below code but it removes all the apostrophe.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in (sample.txt) do (
  set "$line=%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d"
  echo !$line:'=!
  )
  )>out.txt
type out.txt
```

The Ouput coming is :

```
abc,def,123,1abc
xy,mncef,456,cd
```

But I want the single quote to be removed from the position, as integer value will be at a fixed position in each line like here at 3rd.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please [edit] your question and share a [mcve] of your coding attempts! As it stands your question is nothing but a code request which is clearly off-topic here. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask] here! By the way, the "upper commas" are actually called "apostrophes"...

Comment: I guess If we can modify the third token or field in each line by a for loop, we may achieve the results.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite easy using common utilities:

```
$ cat a.txt
'abc','def','123','1abc'
'xy','mncef','456','cd'
$ ./replace.sh 
$ cat a.txt
'abc','def',123,'1abc'
'xy','mncef',456,'cd'
```

And here's the script:

```
$ cat replace.sh 
#!/bin/bash

for i in `egrep -o \'[0-9]+\' a.txt`;do
    sed -i "s/$i/${i:1:${#i}-2}/g" a.txt
done;
```

Comment: Sure, but since this is a Windows-related question you should mention that in your answer...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use sed

```
sed -r "s/'([0-9]+)'/\1/g" filename
```